# Making paper-item a link but keep selected styling

Tags: polymer

Following the docs, I've added an anchor around the paper-item, however a few things slightly complicate the issue.

Firstly, the anchor overrights the color and adds an underline. No biggie, can style that.

Secondly, when used with paper-menu, the iron-selected class which bolds the selected item binds to the anchor and not paper-item.

```
<a name="view1" href="/view1" class="iron-selected">
  <paper-icon-item>
    <iron-icon icon="home" item-icon></iron-icon>
      Home
    </paper-icon-item>
</a>
```

Doing something with css seems pretty backwards?

```
.nav-core__link {
    color: var(--primary-text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-core__link.iron-selected paper-icon-item {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Is there another method available?

Comment: You could move the link into the `paper-icon-item` to maintain consistent styling for `.iron-selected`, but the downside would be the menu item would no longer be a link itself (and you'd have to click the link inside). http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/LRGvJQ?editors=1000

Comment: Thanks mate. Yeah tried that method but I guess they both have downsides.

Comment: you can use `tap` eventListener instead of `anchor`tag